# Class SpannableString not working

Tags: android

Hello good afternoon i need help with the SpannableString class, im very new with this class, so far i have created this piece of code in my onCreate() method:

```
    String texto = "Texto para usar";

    Spannable timeSpannable = new SpannableString(texto.toLowerCase());

    boton.setText(timeSpannable);
```

This does not work, to be sure i have make use of other code from this forum in someone's question while searching for the solution:

```
public static SpannableString highlight(String s, int k) {
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s);
    ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, k, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);


    return ss;
}
```

After, i call the onCreate() method so my programm looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ir);

    boton.setText("Texto para usar");

    boton.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

    boton.setText(highlight(boton.getText().toString(),3));
}
```

This also does not work, so my question is ¿Am i doing anything wrong? ¿Is there any type of restriction when you use the SpannableString class in any API? ¿And finally how should i modify my code in order for it to work?

I am using api 15 in my project and my movil which i run in order to test the app runns api 22:

By the way all of this is because i want to make an search option in my appnote so when someone writes a letter like "s" searchs all the "s" letters and change their colour.

Note that i have searched in this forum for solutions like for 2 days so im posting this after putting effort on searching solutions.

Comment: `SpannableString` works for text views, not sure about buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. It happens to be that buttons have a problem with the function allCaps.

This combined with the fact that since Android 5.0 buttons now have allCaps enabled by default.

This will result in Spannable not working on buttons.

In order to fix this i found two solutions:

**Solution 1**

Remove allCaps from the button through java:

```
String texto = "Texto para usar";
Spannable timeSpannable = new SpannableString(texto);
boton.setAllCaps(false);
boton.setText(timeSpannable);
```

**Solution 2**

Remove allCaps from the Button's layout

```
<Button
...
android:allCaps="false" />
```